# Why are buffers always passed as `&mut [u8]` and not `&mut [MaybeUninit<u8>]`?

Tags: rust, unsafe

```rs
let receiver: Receiver = ...;
let mut buf = [0; 1024]; // allocate a buf that is definitely too big
let bytes_received = reciever.recv(&mut buf);
```

is a relatively common pattern I've seen. To access the data, we might do something like this

```rs
let data = buf[0..bytes_received];
```

It's a fine pattern, but my issue is we're always zeroing a whole array, even if we don't need to. It's not an expensive operation, but it seems strange to ignore it all the time.

An alternative I would propose is this

```rs
use std::mem::{MaybeUninit, transmute};

struct Receiver {
    // just for demonstration...
    data: &'static str, 
}

trait Receive {
    // this is the only required method, since `recv` can be derived from it
    fn recv_maybe_uninit(&mut self, buf: &mut [MaybeUninit<u8>]) -> &[u8];
    
    fn recv(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> usize {
        self.recv_maybe_uninit(unsafe { transmute(buf) }).len()
    }
}

impl Receive for Receiver {
    fn recv_maybe_uninit(&mut self, buf: &mut [MaybeUninit<u8>]) -> &[u8] {
        for (i, byte) in self.data.as_bytes().iter().enumerate() {
            buf[i] = MaybeUninit::<u8>::new(*byte);
            if i == buf.len() {
                return unsafe { transmute(buf) }
            }
        }
        unsafe { transmute(&buf[0..self.data.as_bytes().len()]) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut receiver = Receiver {
        data: "Hello, world!",
    };
    let mut buf = [MaybeUninit::uninit(); 1024];
    let data = receiver.recv_maybe_uninit(&mut buf);

    println!("{:?}", std::str::from_utf8(data).unwrap());
}
```

If `recv_maybe_uninit` is the default, we can easily derive `recv`!

Perhaps a better implementation would be to have the buffer implement a trait that allows it to have `u8`s written to it...

Anyway, why is this style not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the biggest reason that you see `&mut [u8]` for this kind of interface is because that's what the standard library does. Look at the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait:

```
pub trait Read {
    fn read(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<usize>;
    fn read_exact(&mut self, buf: &mut [u8]) -> Result<()> { ... }
    ...
}
```

And the reason the standard library doesn't use `&[MaybeUninit<u8>]` is because `MaybeUninit` didn't exist until 1.36.0 and `Read` was available from the 1.0.0 release. I believe you *could* add it to the trait in a backwards-compatible way, but that would require a default implementation that initializes the uninitialized array so it can be passed to `read`/`read_exact`. See the discussion in [this Rust internals post](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/reading-into-uninitialized-buffers-yet-again/13282).

Another reason would be you are pretty much *forcing* the trait implementer to use `unsafe` to work with a `MaybeUninit` (or at least defer to some other implementation that does use `unsafe` to do the work). This could be improved in the future if/when functions like [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.write_slice) are available, but currently the safe support isn't there yet.

---

That all being said, what you want *is* done in other places like tokio's [`AsyncRead`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/trait.AsyncRead.html) trait. It doesn't use `&mut [MaybeUninit<u8>]` directly, but rather a [`ReadBuf`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/io/struct.ReadBuf.html) which is a safe wrapper around a partially initialized slice of bytes. And that gives you the best of both worlds in my opinion.

There is an RFC to add this kind of implementation to the standard library: [RFC 2930 - read buf](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2930-read-buf.md#summary).

I would recommend following this kind of structure when creating a new read-like API.

Answer (score -8):

First of all, `MaybeUninit` [is quite new](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.uninitialized.html). Especially for arrays most of the api is still in nightly. Should these API's change as the rust version increases? I don't think that is ideal.

Secondly, if library users needs this functionality they can do it just fine themselves.

```
let mut buf: [u8, 1024] = unsafe {std::mem::transmute([MaybeUninit::<u8>::uninit(); 1024]) };
recv.recv(&mut buf)
```

Comment: Passing off uninitiated data as initialized is undefined behavior.

Comment: This is UB, but I did overlook the fact that `MaybeUninit` is new

Comment: I see that in rust docs that `An integer (i*/u*), floating point value (f*), or raw pointer obtained from uninitialized memory, or uninitialized memory` is UB. I can see how my code would do that. But why is that UB?

Comment: @susitsm On one hand, its undefined behavior because the documentation says so. See [this section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initialization-invariant) in the `MaybeUninit` docs: `let x: i32 = unsafe { mem::uninitialized() };` is undefined behavior even if there's no invalid representation for an `i32`. Historically it comes down not to runtime reasons but rather compiler optimization reasons. Rust leans on LLVM and the long-time decisions of C/C++ which ingrained this kind of behavior.